# How to I track loss at epoch using mlflow/tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras, mlflow

I want to use mlflow to track the development of a TensorFlow model. How do I log the loss at each epoch? I have written the following code:

```
mlflow.set_tracking_uri(tracking_uri)

mlflow.set_experiment("/deep_learning")
with mlflow.start_run():
    mlflow.log_param("batch_size", batch_size)
    mlflow.log_param("learning_rate", learning_rate)
    mlflow.log_param("epochs", epochs)
    mlflow.log_param("Optimizer", opt)
    mlflow.log_metric("train_loss", train_loss)
    mlflow.log_metric("val_loss", val_loss)
    mlflow.log_metric("test_loss", test_loss)
    mlflow.log_metric("test_mse", test_mse)
    mlflow.log_artifacts("./model")
```

If I change the train_loss and val_loss to

```
train_loss = history.history['loss']
val_loss = history.history['val_loss']
```

I get the following error:

```
mlflow.exceptions.MlflowException: Got invalid value [12.041399002075195] for metric 'train_loss' (timestamp=1649783654667). Please specify value as a valid double (64-bit floating point)
```

How to I save the the loss and the val_loss at all epochs, so I can visualise a learning curve within mlflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can read [here](https://www.mlflow.org/docs/latest/python_api/mlflow.keras.html#module-mlflow.keras). You can use `mlflow.tensorflow.autolog()` and this, (from doc):

> Enables (or disables) and configures autologging from Keras to MLflow. Autologging captures the following information:
>
> > fit() or fit_generator() parameters; optimizer name; learning rate; epsilon
> > ...

For example:

```
# !pip install mlflow
import tensorflow as tf
import mlflow
import numpy as np


X_train = np.random.rand(100,100)
y_train = np.random.randint(0,10,100)
    

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.Input(100,))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate=.4))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='sigmoid'))        
model.compile(loss = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=False),
              optimizer='Adam', 
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()


mlflow.tensorflow.autolog()
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=100, batch_size=50)
```

Or as you mention in the comment you can use `mlflow.set_tracking_uri()` like below:

```
mlflow.set_tracking_uri('http://127.0.0.1:5000')
tracking_uri = mlflow.get_tracking_uri()
with mlflow.start_run(run_name='PARENT_RUN') as parent_run:
    batch_size=50
    history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=2, batch_size=batch_size)
    mlflow.log_param("batch_size", batch_size)
```

For getting results:

```
!mlflow ui
```

Output:

```
[....] [...] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
[....] [...] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:5000 (****)
[....] [...] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[....] [...] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: ****
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: `.autolog` doesn't work with `mlflow.set_tracking_uri()`. I get this error: `2022/04/13 08:50:33 WARNING mlflow.utils.autologging_utils: Encountered unexpected error during autologging: INVALID_PARAMETER_VALUE:  Model registry functionality is unavailable; got unsupported URI './mlruns' for model registry data storage`. How should I resolve this?

Comment: @ChemBot edited answer. is this solve your problem?

Comment: Do `.autolog` and `mlflow.get_tracking_uri()` not work together?

Comment: `mlflow.tensorflow.autolog()` and `mlflow.set_tracking_uri()` work fine together.